# Add a custom cart item value to WooCommerce order item meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying add order item meta and expect to see it in my {prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta table when user submit order.

I add my value with `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'aa_func_20170206100217', 10, 3 );
function aa_func_20170206100217( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset( $data[ 'selected_date_event' ] ) ) {
        $selected_date_event = [
            'selected_date_event' => $data[ 'selected_date_event' ]
        ];

        return array_merge( $cart_item_data, $selected_date_event );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

And this is works. When I var_dump my cart, there definitely my param exists.

[image]

But when user submit order, I can't find this param in my db.

What did I miss? How it can be stored in order item meta? And which is proper hook for this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save this data in order item meta data:

```
// ADD THE INFORMATION AS ORDER ITEM META DATA SO THAT IT CAN BE SEEN AS PART OF THE ORDER
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','add_product_custom_field_to_order_item_meta', 9, 3 );
function add_product_custom_field_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $item_values, $item_key ) {
    // the meta-key is 'Date event' because it's going to be the label too
    if( ! empty( $item_values['selected_date_event'] ) )
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Date event', sanitize_text_field( $item_values['selected_date_event'] ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> So this will be displayed in Order item data on Order-received, my account Order view and in email notifications.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'aa_func_20170206100217', 10, 3 );
function aa_func_20170206100217( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset( $data[ 'selected_date_event' ] ) ) {
        $selected_date_event = [
            'selected_date_event' => $data[ 'selected_date_event' ]
        ];

        return array_merge( $cart_item_data, $selected_date_event );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', function ( $cartItemData, $cartItemSessionData, $cartItemKey ) {
    if ( isset( $cartItemSessionData['selected_date_event'] ) ) {
        $cartItemData['selected_date_event'] = $cartItemSessionData['selected_date_event'];
    }

    return $cartItemData;
}, 10, 3 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', function ( $data, $cartItem ) {
    if ( isset( $cartItem['selected_date_event'] ) ) {
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => 'selected_date_event',
            'value' => $cartItem['selected_date_event']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', function ( $itemId, $values, $key ) {
    if ( isset( $values['myCustomData'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $itemId, 'selected_date_event', $values['selected_date_event'] );
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```